# Displaying image on Scroll View

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an iPhone application where i want to display three image in each row on scroll view where i need to click action on each image like Photo album in iPhone.  I am not getting any sample code.

Hoping for help

subodh

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of sample code out there, I found [this](http://iappdevs.com/uiimageview-example.jsp) after only basic googling. You want to search for "UIImageView Iphone". It's also worth mentioning that Apple's very own [Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com/) is extremely well written, and will teach you everything you need to know about iPhone programming.

Generally it is frowned down upon to say to look more or read documentation, but you really haven't looked at all. Especially because of Apple's own resource that tells you how to do almost anything, especially something like this. It's not something you can pick up and bits and pieces of and expect to be successful with, it really should be learned starting from the beginning and moving forward. This is especially true if you've never programmed before or are unfamiliar with C/Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Three20 has a photo browser that is open source and works similarly to the iPhone's photo browser with some nice code examples. The images come from an image source object that can relate them to images in your apps bundle or images on the web. Looks like its Google group is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/three20/). I think that to use images in your bundle you use a URL formed like: bundle://image-name.png and not the typical use of the main bundle to get a path to resource.